# Spring boot micro-service is not communicating to the Redis

Tags: redis, kubernetes

I Have deployed few microservices on Kubernetes cluster. Now the problem is these microservices are not communicating to Redis server regardless it is deployed in same Kubernetes cluster or hosted outside. but at the same time if I start the microservice outside of cluster it is able to access both kinds of Redis hosted remotely or deployed in the k8s cluster. I am not getting what I am doing wrong, here are my deployment and service yaml files.

Deployment yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1 
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: redis-master
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: redis
      role: master
      tier: backend
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: redis
        role: master
        tier: backend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: master
        image: redis
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 100Mi
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6379
```

Service yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis-service
spec:
  ports:
    -
      nodePort: 30011
      port: 80
      targetPort: 6379
  selector:
    app: redis
    role: master
    tier: backend
  type: NodePort
```

I Have followed multiple blogs also tried to get help from other sources but didn't work. and also forgot to mention, I am able to access Redis deployed in k8s cluster from the remote machines using Redis desktop manager.

#
k8s cluster is running on-prem in Ubuntu 16.04

#
Microservices when trying from outside k8s running on Windows machine can access redis on k8s cluster and outside of k8s with the same code.

When microservices are trying to communicate with the Redis from inside the cluster getting the following log

```
2019-03-11 10:28:50,650 [main] INFO  org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer - Tomcat started on port(s): 8082 (http)
2019-03-11 10:29:02,382 [http-nio-8082-exec-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2019-03-11 10:29:02,396 [http-nio-8082-exec-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 14 ms
Print : JedisConnectionException - redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
Print : JedisConnectionException - redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
Print : JedisConnectionException - redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
```

Comment: your redis service is not exposed for external connection, how come you could access it from outside of the cluster? do you have any ingress controller running above it?

Comment: Hi @A_Suh Thanks for your response appreciate it, but as per the service YAML above it is exposed to the external network using service type nodePort (`nodePort: 30011`).
and also already mentioned in the problem statement that the same Redis server is accessible from microservice running outside of the Kubernetes cluster.